# Difference or addition on a rose petals

Tags: logical-deduction, visual, calculation-puzzle, grid-deduction

Arrange the numbers 1 to 20 onto the rose petals using these rules :

- Yellow petals contain odd numbers, white petals contain even numbers.
- The outer petals are the difference or addition of the inner petals.
- some numbers have been there as guide.

**Example**
[image]

**Solve this**
[image]

Comment: Looks interesting. For future solvers, note that only the colours of the petal on one layer are necessary.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the answer is unique, but there is my solution :

> [image]